# Is there a setting in SQL Server to keep triggers from firing SELECT @@IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, trigger

This is a SQL Server 2014 Server and we have application code the does a Select `@@Scope_Identity` after an insert into a table.

Recently other developers added triggers to this table and ever since, we are having problems with the triggers firing a `Select @@Identity`.

I know that the default for SQL Server is `@@Identity`, but is there a way to either change the default system wide, or is there a way to keep the triggers from firing the `Select @@Identity`?

When the app connects, `Identity="@@SCOPE_IDENTITY()"` is part of the connection string and it works fine.

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's blog post https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current

Comment: You change the application to call SCOPE_IDENTITY() (no `@@` in there at all).